# Scaling set of rows in a tensor by constant factor

Tags: python, tensorflow

**TL;DR** How to scale part of tensor by 2 (row-indices present in a tf list)

---

Details:

`indices_of_scaling_ids`: Stores list of row_ids
`Tensor("Squeeze:0", dtype=int64, device=/device:GPU:0)`
[1, 4, 5, 6, 12]

`emb_inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, self.all_rows)` 
`#tensor with shape (batch_size=4, all_row_len, emb_size=128)`

So, for every `self.all_rows`, the `emb_inputs` is evaluated.

Question / Challenge faced: I need to scale the `emb_inputs` by `2.0` for every row_ids mentioned in `indices_of_scaling_ids`.
I have tried various splicing things, but can't seem to get to a nice solution. Can someone suggest? Thanks

N.B. Beginner at Tensorflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
SCALE = 2
emb_inputs = ...
indices_of_scaling_ids = ...
emb_shape = tf.shape(emb_inputs)
# Select indices in boolean array
r = tf.range(emb_shape[1])
mask = tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(r[:, tf.newaxis], indices_of_scaling_ids), axis=1)
# Tile the mask
mask = tf.tile(mask[tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis], (emb_shape[0], 1, emb_shape[2]))
# Choose scaled or not depending on indices
result = tf.where(mask, SCALE * emb_inputs, emb_inputs)
```

Comment: This is pure beauty! Thank you! Give me few minutes to try it out

Comment: I tried for a couple of hours to make it work. Could you comment on how to fix the error with this?
https://imgur.com/VjP7F4Z

Many thanks! 
P.S. The 3-d matrix scaling of elements over a list of 2nd-index numbers was making it harder than usual, since axis argument also would not apply, also masking was more intricate to work out

Comment: @VishalAnand I see, the original code worked for me but maybe it depends on the version of TensorFlow whether or not it supports giving just an array for the first dimension only in `tf.where`. I have added a tiling to the code, see if that works for you.

Comment: Finally got it working! Made a minor edit to the answer (iterating over 2nd-index, 1st-index refers to batch number).
Thanks again!

Comment: @VishalAnand Thanks for the fix, I had misread some bits of the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem at all! I learnt more from this than most tutorials